# how can I resolve alias components in next.js with ts-jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, next.js, ts-jest

I use typescript,nextjs and Jest, I want to use aliases in my tsconfig instead of using "../../..", that workes but when I add Jest, I can't config it correctly.

and this is my tsconfig.json :

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true, 
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@providers/*": ["./src/providers/*"],
      "@themes/*": ["./src/themes/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["./src/assets/*"],
      "@c/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
      "@store/*": ["./src/store/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

so, when I run "jest", it gives me an error because of not resolving aliases in imports

I think documentation of ts-jest does not explain this, and I need solution for resolve it.

```sh
> test
> jest

 PASS  src/__tests__/index.test.tsx (10.651 s)
  MainPage
    ✓ one equal by one (2 ms)

 FAIL  src/components/Body/index.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module @themes/DatePickerTheme mapped as:
    [
      "/home/kourosh/Documents/projects/vandapayment/frontend/frontend-web-app/themes/DatePickerTheme"
    ].
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/themes\/(.*)/": "[
          "/home/kourosh/Documents/projects/vandapayment/frontend/frontend-web-app/themes/$1"
        ]"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

      1 | import { Box, Flex, VStack } from "@chakra-ui/react";
      2 | import { DatePicker, RangeDatePicker } from "jalali-react-datepicker";
    > 3 | import { DatePickerTheme } from "@themes/DatePickerTheme";
        | ^
      4 | export default function Body() {
      5 |   return (
      6 |   

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:579:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Body/index.tsx:3:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.424 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution and solved my problem
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest
check this repository
and do same this:

and in jest.config.js do same below:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",

    "^@/pages/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/pages/$1",
    "^@/services/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/services/$1",
  },
```